# Angular2 cookies instead of localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, angular

I managed to make all work JWT auth, no problems there, but it only supports modern browsers, and I need Auth to work in all starting from IE9 and upwards.

I could not find any info or examples how to use cookies in Angular2. There is a simple example using localStorage for saving token, I need the same functionality but done with cookies.

Any help would be great, since there isn't anything on this on the net.

```
this.http.post("http://localhost:3001/sessions/create", creds, { headers: header })
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
      data => localStorage.setItem('id_token',data.id_token),
      err => this.logError(err),
      () => console.log("Auth is completed!")
    );
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A simple way to solve this is use this lib:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-cookies

To install this library, run:

```
$ npm install ng2-cookies
```

Usage:

```
import { Cookie } from 'ng2-cookies/ng2-cookies';

Cookie.set('cookieName', 'cookieValue');
Cookie.set('cookieName', 'cookieValue', 10 /*days from now*/);
Cookie.set('cookieName', 'cookieValue', 10, '/myapp/', 'mydomain.com');

let myCookie = Cookie.get('cookieName');

/*
* List of cookies as Object, like: { cookieName: "cookieValue", cookieName2: "cookieValue2" ... etc }
*/
let cookielist = Cookie.getAll();

Cookie.delete('cookieName');
Cookie.deleteAll();
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 4):

I implemented the cookie service with the functions from Angular 1 to the Angular 2 as an injectable service. Also added a `removeAll` function as a plus. You can get it with:

```
npm install angular2-cookie --save
```

After injecting it as a service, you can use the methods as in Angular 1:

```
this._cookieService.get(key);
this._cookieService.getObject(key);
// Other available methods are
// put(), putObject(), remove() and removeAll()
```

You can check the readme part for examples and available functions.

https://github.com/salemdar/angular2-cookie

Answer (score 1):

For use cookie in angular first run `npm` command `npm install angular2-cookie --save`,
After injecting your service in `app.module.ts` add

```
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/services/cookies.service';
```

or add service in provider,

```
 providers: [CookieService]
```

after adding a cookie to your component where you used
there are 7 methods for cookies 
1.)`get():- This method returns the value of given cookie key.`
2.)`getObject() :- This method is returns the desterilized value of given cookie key`.
3.)`get all():- This method returns a key-value object with all the cookies.`
4.)`put():- This method is used to set a value for given cookie key.`
5.)`putObject():- This method is used to serializes and set a value for given cookie key.`
6.)`remove(): -This method is used to remove given cookie`.
7.)`remove all(): -This method is used to remove all cookies.`

for put/set value in a cookie :`this._cookieService.put('key:string', 'value:string');` here key as your cookie name ex:`user1` and value is for set `any value`.
for get value in a cookie:`this._cookieService.get('key');`
for remove cookie from component then `this._cookieService.remove('key');`