# Typescript importing Modules (ngCookies)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have downloaded a sample of an admin dashboard in Typescript/Angular. It's built up in a very modular way with .component, .routing, .module files.

Now I need to import the cookie module. I was used to import modules by injecting them into a Component constructor from what I've read, but the Angular documentation says that I need to use the

```
angular.module('app', ['ngCookies']);
```

directive to import it.

So I tried it but it gives me an error (cannot find 'angular'). I think the problem might be that its meant for javascript.

Can anyone help me with a minimal example of importing cookies in typescript?

Comment: Any chance you're mixing up AngularJS (1.x) and Angular (2+)?

Comment: you want to get cookie module for angular, if so you can check these links 


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495635/angular2-cookies-instead-of-localstorage

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cookie

Comment: I think im mixing up yes, ng2 means Angular 2 then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These comments set me on the right track.
If anyone struggles with this,

use

```
import { CookieService } from 'ng2-cookies';
```

then in the Component

```
@Component{(
    providers: [ CookieService ]
})
```

now it works with constructor injection