# How to implement security in Headless Architecture(using Angular)

Tags: angular, security, roles, headless

In our project we are exposing every thing as services ( i.e. API ) How to implement security in this architecture. Front end of the application is Angular. Since roles, operators are not there in the application. How to implement security using Angular. Its really difficult to find solutions with this new architecture ( Headless approach)

Any help ???

Answer (score 1):

Depends on many things
What cloud service are you on e.g.
Generally you will generate a token and pass it back as a private cookie

You may want to implement something like https://jwt.io/

Comment: @CharanjitRana refer to this post for token storage : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301690/angular-2-4-where-to-store-token/46302131#46302131